# Minimum no of comparison required to divide array of 16 integer in two equal parts?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, median

Example:

```
a={15,12,3,10,5,6,16,13,9,4,11,2,8,14,1,7} 
a1={1,3,2,4,6,5,8,7} 
a2={13,10,11,14,12,16,15,9}
```

both list contain 8 element.One list contain all element less than medians and other will contain more than median.I told my interviewer to use quickselect but he told me that quickselect don't work well for small size array.It work when number of elements are larger.I suggest him to do median of median but he replied that it will take more comparison to first find pseudo median and compare that number against all number to find & divide them into two parts.Oh ! it is pseudo :( .I was speechless.Anyone like to help me ?

Comment: Median of median relies on the magic pivot number 5, which should be the reason why it takes more operations than directly computing overall median.

Comment: If you consider "median of medians" to be an essential part of quickselect, then the claim may be correct; in practice, stochastic quickselect is usually faster than m-of-m but I think quickselect doesn't depend on m-of-m. If you have SIMD available, you can do multiple comparisons in parallel; if both the list and the numbers are small enough, you might be able to accomplish the partition using only N comparison *instructions* (with no conditional branches), which could be a useful optimization if that were a common case and you know what the CPUs are.